# DrawColumnCell on EnhDBGrid1

Tags: delphi

I want to color some rows based on the field values and it doesn't work on EnhDbgrid component (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199506/Improving-Delphi-TDBGrid)

this is the code :

```
procedure TForm15.EnhDBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);

begin
  if adoquery1.FieldByName('N1').AsString = 'Gerencia General' then
    EnhDBGrid1.Canvas.font.Color := clRed
  else
    EnhDBGrid1.Canvas.font.Color := clYellow;
  (sender as tEnhDBGrid).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We can't see your screen.  In what respect does it not work?

Comment: does adoquery1 assigned to this grid? does function "EnhDBGrid1DrawColumnCell" calling?

Comment: Yes adoquery1 is assigned to this grid. I can't change colors . The grid draws the cells always with colors defined in properties.